# Edition/Answer and Last-Activity tag in the main board

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, questions

When `editing` a question we now have something like:

> 1m ago userX 2000

Saying that 1 minute ago `userX` edited a question. Although it doesn't say anymore who asked the question (lets call the asker `userQ`). The same procedure happens when if `userY` replies a question asked my `userX`.

I understand that the aim of this message is to show when was the last activity on the question, but wouldn't it be better if it was something like:

> E: 1m ago userX 2000, Q: 10m ago userQ 1999

And for an answer:

> A: 1m ago userY 1998, Q: 1h ago userQ 1999

*`Q` and `A` just like in the search engine.*

Comment: This is probably deliberate since the StackExchange philosophy is that it is the question that is important, not who asked it. Also, if there are multiple answers, who do you show as the answerer? I'm not sure there is enough space there to accurately describe the (common) situation where the question is being actively answered and edited, and the information is only a click away in any case.

Comment: If the question is the important point why putting the name & the reputation of the one asking it, replying or editing? Since the current policy is to say who did the last action on the question, in case of multiple answers it would be enough to specify who last replied the question. Same principle as now, just specifying whether the last action was an answer or an edit and giving the credit to the one who asked the question: *Reddite quae sunt Caesaris, Caesari*.

Comment: "...giving the credit to the one who asked the question..." - if the question is a good one, he is already able to get credit through upvotes; you consider this insufficient?

Comment: I consider that naming him in the main board could be interesting. I'm not talking about giving him "proper" credits through upvotes, just reminding others who asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how "activity-sort" questions lists work. You'll notice a similar behavior on [the active questions list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and the various hot lists.

The change you propose would make this extremely verbose; in practice, it would require two lines and be considerably more difficult to scan.

Several people have suggested changes that would add a small bit of text noting the *nature* of the activity that pushed the question to the front page. See: [Can we add 'asked', 'answered', 'edited' text to each question featured on the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145039/can-we-add-asked-answered-edited-text-to-each-question-featured-on-the-f)

Note also that if you click on that timestamp it'll take you to whatever post (question or answer) had the last activity.